# How to fix error when trying to run node web-server.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, powershell

I've installed node.js through Win8 powershell and now want to run the web-server.js that comes with the AngularJS tutorial.. however, this time around Windows8 Powershell is behaving differently from my experience in Win7 - I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\xx\angular-phonecat\scripts [master +24 ~0 -0 !]> web-server.js
web-server.js : The term 'web-server.js' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ web-server.js
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (web-server.js:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Suggestion [3,General]: The command web-server.js was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type ".\web-server.js". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run using the following command:

```
node web-server.js
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script fil
```